# Django signals redirect

Tags: django, python-3.x, redirect

when a user logs in,I check if it belongs to a specific group, if this is true I do a redirect to a specific page, here is my code apps.py:

```
def OperatorRedirect(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    from struttura_employee.models import EmployeeUser, EmployeeGroup

    u = get_object_or_404(EmployeeUser,username=user.username)
    groups = u.get_groups()
    g = get_object_or_404(EmployeeGroup,long_name="Operatore")
    if g in groups:
        print("sei un operatore")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('qrs_machine_panel:asset_choice', args=[]))

class QrsofmanMachinePanelConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'qrsofman_machine_panel'
    print("ciao")
    user_logged_in.connect(OperatorRedirect)
```

the problem is that HttpResponseRedirect is being ignored
any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't a thing that you can do in a signal. Those are for things like updating a database row, or sending an email, when a specific action happens. They can't affect the response in any way, because that is managed by the view.

Your redirection code needs to move into the login view itself; just do the check after you call `auth.login()`.

Comment: In addition to what Daniel mention, you should also use the [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test) decorator at your login view; otherwise users can simply type the URL of a restricted view.