# Django - Update User at login

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm actually working on a django project and i'm migrating to a CustomUser model. On the database everything have gone well and now i want to force my user to update their informations (to respect the new model)

I would like to do it when they login (I set all the e-mail to end with @mysite.tmp in order to know if they have already update it or not). So if the e-mail end with this they should be automatically redirected to the update user view (without having been logged) and when they submit the form they get logged in (if the form is valid of course).

So my question is how to make this happened at login? I could override the login function but it does not seems to be the better option. Is there a view that i can override? What will you recommend to me?

EDIT: With your response i finally chose to override the `logged_in` signal and add a check on the `loggin_required` decorator that check if the user is up-to-date. Now my issue is that I don't understand what a signal is and so how to override it. Is it a method of the User model I have to override, in this case it would be quite simple, or is it somewhere else?
Could you explain me, or link me to an easy to understand documentation on this subject?

PS: I'm working with django 1.11 and python 3.6

Comment: I think the best option is to use `user_logged_in` signal. Here is the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_in

Comment: I would prefer to not login the user before he update his profile. Such that he cant access into the registered part of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I progressed a bit but I still have a problem. Here is my action when I got the login signal:

```
def login_test(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
  if(user.email.endswith('@mysite.tmp')):
    print('logged in with old user')
    #and now redirect to my view
user_logged_in.connect(login_test)
```

My function work well, the message get print in the console when needed but I don't know how to make a redirection. I tried with redirect and render but it does nothing, i'm still redirected to the standard redirect link when a user logged in successfully.

EDIT: after looking on the web i found that it was not possible to do a redirection inside a signal, for more information on this look this post: [Django signals redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36010758/django-signals-redirect).
Therefore I write a custom Login view extending the one of django:

```
class LoginView(BasicLoginView):
  def get_success_url(self):
    if self.resquest.user.email.endswith('@mysite.tmp'):
      return resolve_url('edit-profile')
    else:
      return super().get_success_url()
```

With this it work perfectly fine!

Thank's again for your response that have helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want the user to be logged-in at all before he update his profile, I think you will need to subclass the built-in login view and override the `form_valid` method on it:

```
# views.py
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
     """Custom login view to force the users to update themselves before login"""

     def form_valid(self, form):
          """Check if we should allow the user to login"""

          user = form.get_user()

          # Here you can check if the user is an old one or not
          if '@mysite.tmp' in user.email:
              # The user should be updated, redirect to the update view
              return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('update-view'))
          else:
              # The user is already updated, call the base `form_valid`
              return super().form_valid(form)
```

And use this view in your urls:

```
# urls.py
from .views import CustomLoginView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^auth/login', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login')
]
```

I see kind of a problem with this method though. You will need to make the update view of your user not requiring a logged-in user...

Comment: I finally will use the logged in signal, i prefer not to let the update view not requiring a logged-in user. But i got some issues, i don't really understand what is this logged_in method. I saw it's a signal but dont understand this concept and don't know how to implement it.